# Use of the synchronize keyword

Tags: android, synchronized, loader, android-cursor

I'm new to **synchronized blocks**, still not sure if this is how they are used. Basically I'm decoding a lot of bitmaps in a secondary thread, adding them to a `List` and finally setting the list to an entity object called `myEntity`.

My question would be, when sychronizing, should I synchronize the object I want to call a method on (even if it is non-final), or a generic `Object` (which is usually called `lock` or `mLock` ? (look at the code to see what I mean)

PS: `myEntity` **is not a final field, cause it is initialized `onLoadFinished()` loader callback**

```
// Inside AsyncTask subclass
@Override
public void doInBackground() {
    List<Picture> list = new ArrayList<Picture>();

    Cursor cursor = database.getBitmapPathsForId(id);

    do {
        list.add(Picture.fromCursor(cursor));
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());

    // HERE
    synchronized (myEntity) {
        myEntity.setPictures(list);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: sorry got carried away writing the code example that forgot to ask it

Comment: the only important thing is that all the calls that have to be synchronized are so on the same object, and that this object is never used for another, unrelated, synchronization block.

Comment: so, the synchronized block I wrote is ok?

Comment: it is. I don't really know what purpose it serves, since I don't see where else `myEntity` is locked, but yes.

Comment: I am not sure, I'm new with the synchronized keyword. The reason I locked `myEntity` is because it's being called from a secondary thread, and the main thread is also setting some values. But I'm not sure if synchronization is even necessary

Comment: if your threads are not modifying the same value, it is not necessary. Even if they are modifying the same value, a `assignation` is an atomic operation, and synchronized does not give you any clue as too the order of execution. Synchronization is important if you are calling methods that, if called at the same time, could result in inconsistent data or a concurrency error. (such as a method that would loop on a list using a fast enum and a method that would be removing an item in that list.)